# Android Lollipop: Cannot include an external layout inside of a GridLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to include an external layout file that contains a GridLayout inside a GridLayout. My code works for API 23+, but does not work for API 21 or API 22 (Lollipop). Below is my code for **activity_main.xml**, in which I include the layout **textcomparator.xml**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:rowCount="1"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <!-- Text comparison UI -->
            <include
                android:id="@+id/text_comparator"
                layout="@layout/textcomparator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is my code for **textcomparator.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:rowCount="1"
        android:columnCount="2">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textbox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:hint="Text 1"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textbox2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:hint="Text 2"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="" />
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the screenshot for API 22 (**not working**):
[image]
Below is the screenshot for API 23 (**working**):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to recall that the implementation of *GridLayout* in the framework was a little buggy pre API 23. The *TextViews* have a zero width in APIs 21 and 22. (You can see this in the layout inspector of Android Studio - *Tools->Layout Inspector*.) This is because the layout weights are not working. You should be using the AndroidX version which actually works better.

```
implementation "androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0"
```

The support library version will also work.

Here is what you code would look like with AndroidX. I think that the XML for the support library will be the same except you would reference the support library version of *GridLayout* and not the AndroidX version.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:columnCount="1"
            app:orientation="vertical"
            app:rowCount="1"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <!-- Text comparison UI -->
            <include
                android:id="@+id/text_comparator"
                layout="@layout/textcomparator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_row="0"
                app:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the included file:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:rowCount="1"
        app:columnCount="2">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textbox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:hint="Text 1"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textbox2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:hint="Text 2"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="" />
    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

A quick test on an emulator running API 22 shows the following:

[image]

This is what is expected.

Comment: this solution works with api 21(android 5.0)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `androidx` then this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59888704/1162154) works, But if you don't use `androidx` then follow the below instructions:
1.Add the following dependency in your `app.gradle` file

```
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
```

2.Replace **`GridLayout`** with **`android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`** in both `textcomparator.xml` and `activity_main.xml` layout files 
3.Replace all the following attributes

```xml
android:rowCount
android:columnCount
android:orientation
android:layout_row
android:layout_column
android:layout_columnWeight
```

with these attributes

```
app:rowCount
app:columnCount
app:orientation
app:layout_row
app:layout_column
app:layout_columnWeight
```

Your final code should be like this: 
**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:columnCount="1"
            app:orientation="vertical"
            app:rowCount="1"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <!-- Text comparison UI -->
            <include
                android:id="@+id/text_comparator"
                layout="@layout/textcomparator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_row="0"
                app:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**textcomparator.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:rowCount="1"
        app:columnCount="2">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textbox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:hint="Text 1"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textbox2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:hint="Text 2"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have tested it on API 21 and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Gradle, and in your build.gradle file add the following section at the end:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

Then execute assembleDebug gradle task.